# Reading and printing url to excel file

Tags: vba, dom

This is my first VBA code and I am trying the following:

```
Sub myFirstCode()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
With ie
    .Visible = False
    .navigate "http://www.ercot.com/content/cdr/html/real_time_spp"
```

Beyond the above code I am not able to figure how to print the value 18.45 in cell A2. Value 18.45 is as shown in the attached image.[image]

I know I need to use something of this sort:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = ????
```

Comment: Excel has an "import from the web" feature on the Data tab, recording a macro of that process as a starting point will probably be simpler.

Comment: I need to write the code as this is not standalone activity.

Comment: I mean that if you record a macro Excel will generate VBA code that you can then hack around with.

Comment: The answer to this question will be the steps needed to get from the IE document object to the individual 'td' element, and reading the text in that element. But you'll have to provide more information about the HTML in the page; browsing to the URL mentioned in your question returns an **Access denied** page. If you were to try this in Javascript or Python, could you describe the necessary steps? As long as you are using the W3C DOM, the conversion from other languages to VBA is usually quite straightforward.

Comment: The URL works fine at my end. Am I not reading it correctly in the VBA?

Comment: For starters the big red arrow in your post points to the third column which would make it "C2", not "A2".

Comment: Anything to do with ercot seems to be off limits here. Even the homepage.